# PHP: filter_input_array(). Can you count the number of elements in a "type" argument's associated super global without using said super global?

Tags: php, filter

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

`filter_input_array()`

```
mixed filter_input_array ( int $type [, mixed $definition [, bool $add_empty = true ]] )
```

**Possbile `$type` values**:

```
INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_SERVER, or INPUT_ENV
```

Is it possible to count the number of elements associated with the "type" argument (which is an integer) *without referencing a super global*? Since the "type" argument is an integer, I do not think the following would work.

**Non-working example:**

```
count(INPUT_POST);
```

My goal is to test the result of counting the elements associated with the "type" argument to see if at least the minimum, or at most the maximum, number of elements were submitted. Range checking is not a problem for me. Getting the count of external super global elements without using a super global is my problem.

Using `filter_has_var()` in a loop with an array and a counter *will not suffice* because that would *only count the elements I want to filter that are also present in a given "type" argument's (INPUT_POST, INPUT_GET, ...) associated super global ($_POST, $_GET)*.

If more elements are present than what I want to allow, or less elements are present than are required, my program should throw an exception and take appropriate action.

Comment: `filter_input_array` is filtering the superglobal.  The type is just telling the function which one to filter.  Use the superglobal.

Comment: @AbraCadaver. This, I know. The point of the question and scenario is that there is no use in filtering if 1) not enough required elements are submitted, or 2) too many elements are submitted. `filter_input_array()` allows you to circumvent super globals. So, I am looking for another way to circumvent them so that I can count the number of elements without using things like $_POST and $_GET. You use the PHP filter functions so that you do not have to use superglobals to sanitize and validate. If you read carefully, I think you will this idea understand this idea better.

Comment: It doesn't allow you to "circumvent" superglobals.  It returns the asked for superglobal, either filtered or unchanged.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm willing to accept that if you present some documentation. The PHP filter functions have access to the source of external arrays, but that does not mean the filter functions are using superglobals.

Comment: The problem of not being able to count the number of submitted external array elements at the same level that the PHP filter functions operate.

Comment: I had never given this a thought but you raise a really good point. I would be curious to know how it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want to use the superglobal because that's the data that `filter_input_array` is using,  though it appears that it uses the "as submitted data" and not the actual superglobal.  Without using the superglobal you're best bet would be something like:

```
if( ($count = count($filtered = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST))) > 2 && $count < 5 ) {
    //use $filtered
} else {
    //error
}
```

You could define this as a function and pass in min and max values.

Otherwise, you're not going to be able to count the entries in `$_POST` without `count($_POST)`.  You either use `filter_input_array` to have access to the unmodified data as it was submitted, or you use the superglobal which will reflect any changes you made to it.

Comment: It may not be true that `filter_input_array()` uses the superglobals. Read the manual about `filter_input_array()`, the comments section.

Comment: If you mean _"Looks like filter_input_array isn't aware of changes to the input arrays that were made before calling filter_input_array."_ then yes that appears to be the case.  So you either use the filter function for the data as submitted regardless of changes, or use the superglobal.

Comment: It seems that there should be a way to count what the filter functions see, at the time and level that they see it.

Comment: Does `filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)` return an associative array? If so, does it return it by *value* or *reference*? This could be a **dangerous** sequence of code to run on submitted form data without that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
count(filter_input_array(INPUT_SERVER));
count(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST));
count(filter_input_array(INPUT_GET));
```

.
.
.

What you do from here is up to you.